# Using Select Into Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having problems with a Select Into Statement.  I am trying to determine the quantity and sales amount of  each product sold during the period of a month.  I need to select the sum of sales and the sum of quantity into two variables. I need to include the idproduct in the select statment, because I need to group the sum of quantity and sum of sames by the product's ID.  Here is what I have so far.

```
select bt.idproduct, sum(bt.price), sum(bt.quantity)
into dummy1, v_sumsales, v_sumquantity
from bb_basket bb inner join bb_basketitem bt
using (idbasket)
where TO_CHAR(dtordered, 'MON')  = 'FEB' and TO_CHAR(dtordered, 'YYYY') = '2012'
group by(bt.idproduct);
```

Here is the error message I keep getting:

> ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
>   ORA-06512: at line 8
>   01422. 00000 -  "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"
>   *Cause:    The number specified in exact fetch is less than the rows returned.
>   *Action:   Rewrite the query or change number of rows requested

I believe the problem is that I am selecting multiple product IDs into the dummy variable.  I need to use the select into statement, but I only want to select into the latter two variables.  How can I do this?

All variables in this coding have been declared properly

Comment: Why do you think this will only return one row?  there is no constraint in your query on bt.idproduct, so if there is more than one idproduct, yes, it will return multiple rows.  You can't return multiple rows into a scalar variable.  So, either add a clause for "bt.idproduct = xxx" or change to a cursor of some sorts

Comment: That's what I did, and the procedure worked.  I don't know if it returned the correct values, but I think I'm in good shape.  Thank you for your help.